# String shifting

Tags: java, string

I looked and looked for this, but can't find a proper answer.

Anyways, here's the problem:

Below is the function shiftString() with type parameters of String and Integer. Fill in the code to shift the parameter string characters by the shift amount. Example: "testing" shifted by 2 would equal "ngtesti" and "testing" shifted by -2 would equal "stingte".

Here's my code:

```
public class Main {

public String shiftString(String string, int shift) {

   String answer = string.substring(string.length() - shift) + string.substring(0, string.length() - shift);
    return answer;
}
```

Here's my error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -6    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1875) at ghtBQvETRGjbIqd$Main.shiftString(ghtBQvETRGjbIqd.java:6) at ghtBQvETRGjbIqd.(ghtBQvETRGjbIqd.java:14)    at ghtBQvETRGjbIqd.main(ghtBQvETRGjbIqd.java:11)

Comment: -6 index on a string? you can't read from before the string starts...

Comment: You must have passed in a shift amount that is `6` more than the length of the string you passed in.

Comment: Two problems with your code: (1) you need to check that value of `shift` is not large than string's length (that's what is causing the exception you are getting), and (2) when shift is negative, this just does not work at all, you need a different algorithm for that case.

Comment: @dima something like circular array ?

Comment: For a quick and dirty hack, you can use
index = ( shift + SOME_BIG_NUMBER * string.length() ) % string.length()

That way even when 'shift' is negative, the index stays positive

Comment: @Dima I added a check, like you suggested, I get no errors, but I can't do negative shifting, that's what I need help with. Here's the new code: http://pastebin.com/4PExT8r7

Comment: @Cory there is an answer below, showing how to handle negative shift. Does it help? (I'd use `-shift` instead of `Math.abs`, but it seems to be doing the job either way).

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work...

```
shift = ( ( shift % string.length() ) + string.length() ) % string.length;
```

The first % gets it into range ( -string.length() .. string.length() )

The addition gets it into range ( 0 .. 2*string.length() )

The final % gets it into range [ 0 .. string.length() )

(Of course, then just concatenate substrings [shift .. string.length()-1] and [0 .. shift])

Answer (score 0):

Handle edge cases where shift is greater than string length.

Handle case when there is negative, then you substring from length - shift to length and concatinate from 0 to length - shift

Handle case when there is positive shift it is from shift+1 to length concatinate with 0 to shift

```
public static String shiftString(String string, int shift) {
   if(Math.abs(shift) > string.length()) return string; //or exception
   boolean negative = shift != Math.abs(shift);
   shift = Math.abs(shift);
   return negative? string.substring(string.length()-shift, string.length()) + string.substring(0, string.length()-shift) : string.substring(shift+1) + string.substring(0, shift);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Break it down, simplify. This solution is not very fast but for educational purposes, you should keep it nice and tidy rather than super optimized:

```
@Test
public void tests() {
    assertThat(last("abc"), is('c'));
    assertThat(first("abc"), is('a'));
    assertThat(shiftRight("abc"), is("cab"));
    assertThat(shiftLeft("abc"), is("bca"));
    assertThat(shiftString("testing", 2), is("ngtesti"));
    assertThat(shiftString("testing", -2), is("stingte"));

    assertThat(shiftString("testing", 999), is("stingte")); // Big numbers should work
}


public String shiftString(String string, int shift) {
    if (shift == 0) {
        return string;
    }

    if (shift > 0) {
        return shiftString(shiftRight(string), shift - 1);
    } else {
        return shiftString(shiftLeft(string), shift + 1);
    }
}

private String shiftLeft(final String string) {
    return string.substring(1) + first(string);
}

private String shiftRight(final String string) {
    return last(string) + string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
}

private char last(final String string) {
    return string.charAt(string.length() - 1);
}

private char first(final String string) {
    return string.charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
int length=string.length();
String answer = string.substring((length-shift)%length)+string.substring(0,(length-shift)%length);
System.out.println(answer);
```